# What is the role of Google's Dart programming language?

Tags: dart

I am having a hard time understanding what the major purpose of Google's programming language Dart is. What's its role?  Why would I want to use it?

Comment: Dart is an "multi-side" language :). run as client-side and server-side at the same time. will be limited to Chrome only.

Comment: @Kakashi to be clear, native Dart support will be limited to Chrome only at first, but it compiles to Javascript to support any modern browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may checkout the technical aspects on [this article](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/index.html). Quote:

> The Dart programming language is presented here in its early stages.
> The following design goals will guide the continued evolution and
> refinement of this open source project:
>
> - Create a structured yet flexible programming language for the web.
> - Make Dart feel familiar and natural to programmers and thus easy to
>   learn.
> - Ensure that all Dart language constructs allow high performance
>   and fast application startup.
> - Make Dart appropriate for the full range
>   of devices on the web—including phones, tablets, laptops, and servers.
> - Provide tools that make Dart run fast across all major modern
>   browsers.
>
> These design goals address the following problems currently
> facing web developers:
>
> - Small scripts often evolve into large web applications with no
>   apparent structure—they’re hard to debug and difficult to maintain. In
>   addition, these monolithic apps can’t be split up so that different
>   teams can work on them independently. It’s difficult to be productive
>   when a web application gets large.
> - Scripting languages are popular
>   because their lightweight nature makes it easy to write code quickly.
>   Generally, the contracts with other parts of an application are
>   conveyed in comments rather than in the language structure itself. As
>   a result, it’s difficult for someone other than the author to read and
>   maintain a particular piece of code.
> - With existing languages, the
>   developer is forced to make a choice between static and dynamic
>   languages. Traditional static languages require heavyweight toolchains
>   and a coding style that can feel inflexible and overly constrained.
> - Developers have not been able to create homogeneous systems that
>   encompass both client and server, except for a few cases such as
>   Node.js and Google Web Toolkit (GWT).
> - Different languages and formats
>   entail context switches that are cumbersome and add complexity to the
>   coding process.

Comment: +1 Good, unbiased and well written.

Comment: Okay its starting to make sense is it going to be able to function like php as a server side programming lanuage there for web developers will only need to learn dart html css

Answer (score 3):

Major purpose of dart language is replacement of JavaScript. It fixes common issues of JavaScript, it is actually compiled to JavaScript, but in the future it will have its own VM.

Main advantages over JavaScript are that it is object oriented interface inheritance based language, it has support for interface factory builders. It has simpliefed actor model called isolators.

Comment: It can't "compile to javascript". I urge you to read the meaning of compilation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler The correct term would be "translator".

Comment: so its kinda like what happened with php where it did its thing and worked for large projects but was hard to manage but when php added objects and other things it be came alot more powerful system. The differance is  that this is a new lanauge while php is the same. Hopefully the vm will not take to long to be realsied

Comment: @ChristianSciberras I think "transforms source code written in a programming language into another computer language" describes the process pretty well.

Comment: The major purpose of Dart is to help developers from many different backgrounds write awesome apps for the web. Replacing JavaScript isn't the purpose of Dart.